# python dynamically create class with inner class

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming, tastypie, metaclass

I'm using django-tastypie and I need to create classes like this from my django models:

```
class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

Since I have a lot of models in my django app I don't want to repeat myself, and use type() function instead to create all that resource classes. The problem is I don't know how to deal with this inner "Meta" class.

Can you give me an example of how to dynamically create a class with inner class using type()?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class MyModel(object) : pass
modelClass = MyModel()

class ModelResource(object):
    def mymethod(self):
        print('got here')

Meta = type('Meta', (object, ), {'allowed_methods': ['get']})

def add_mymethod(cls):
    def mymethod(self):
        super(cls, self).mymethod()
    cls.mymethod = mymethod
    return cls

name = modelClass.__class__.__name__ + "Resource"
MyModelResource = add_mymethod(type(name, (ModelResource, ),
                                    {'Meta':Meta, }))

print(MyModelResource.Meta)
# <class '__main__.Meta'>

m = MyModelResource()
m.mymethod()
# got here
```

The inner class, `Meta`, is just another attribute as far as `MyModelResource` is concerned.

---

Methods are also just attributes as far as `MyModelResource` is concerned. Actually, you define a *function* in `MyModelResource.__dict__`, and the Python attribute lookup mechanism 
causes `inst.mymethod` to return a bound *method*.

There is no problem referring to `MyModelResource` in the `super` call

```
super(MyModelResource, self).mymethod()
```

before `MyModelResource` is defined, because name lookups are performed at run time, not at the time `mymethod` is defined.

---

You are absolutely correct that

```
super(self.__class_, self).mymethod()
```

is wrong. This will spoil all that is good about `super`. If `MyModelResource` were to be subclassed, and an instance of the subclass were to call `mymethod`, then Python would fall into an infinite loop.

Comment: This is correct answer. Now, what if I have to define method that calls super() inside? I want to avoid writing super(self.__class__, self) because apparently is not a good idea...

Comment: the problem is I don't know name of the class in the moment of defining method. In my case creation of class looks like this: type(modelClass.__class__.__name__ + "Resource",(ModelResource, ), {"Meta"... So I cant refer to it by name in the method.

Comment: Okay, so `mymethod` can not be defined until after `MyModelResource` is defined. In that case, use a class decorator. I've added the class decorator, `add_mymethod` as an example.